# Moshi Json name annotation property not working

Tags: android, kotlin, moshi

I'm trying to use @Json(name = "Result") property to change the field name and it's not working. The result is always null from retrofit response, but if I use the actual "Result" in the field it is working fine, here's the example data class.

Not Working:

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class SMSResponse(
   @Json(name = "Result")
   val smsName: String?
)
```

Also Not working when using @field:Json(name = "Result")

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class SMSResponse(
   @field:Json(name = "Result")
   val smsName: String?
)
```

Working:

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class SMSResponse(
   val Result: String?
)
```

Dependency: (Latest Moshi Version)

```
implementation("com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.14.0")
ksp("com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.15.0")
```

Network Call:

```
return Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
        .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .build()
```

I also added moshi proguard.

Comment: Why do you add `GsonConverterFactory` if you already use Moshi?

Comment: how's your json? Do you have an example pls?

Comment: @Fred it's just a simple { "Result": "Banana Leaf" }

Comment: Don't use moshi-kotlin (reflection) when you're using code-gen. That's an aside. Without seeing a minimum runnable test case, my only guess on the cause of your problem is proguard or whatever code rearranger ruining something.

Comment: @TamHuynh It seems you;re right for questioning the Gson, it has conflict with moshi I guess. Thank you

For EricCochran You're also right when mentioning rearranger and ruining something so it is Gson who ruined it. Thank you

Comment: Maybe the order of adding matters too, what if you add `Moshi` converter before `Gson`? Somewhere in the code of Retrofit, It seems like they pick the first converter in the list that matches the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
val moshi =  Moshi
                .Builder()
                .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
                .build()



 return    Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
    .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
    .client(okHttpClient)
    .build()
```

Comment: Tried it and it and still the same. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by removing         `.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))`.
It seems the Moshi and Gson Converter factory cannot be in the same builder.